# Android method not being called, but log is being printed

Tags: android, android-studio, user-interface

so I have an interface method which is being called,verified by the fact that a log is being printed in logcat, but the method inside the interface method isn't being called. The onCenterEvent: picture taken log is printed, but the logs inside pictureTaken() aren't, and nothing happens (Picture taken is a UI trigger method inside of a viewmodel). Any reason why this would happen?

I have tried removing the method and putting the logic in onCenterEvent() also, but that doesn't work either.

Below is the interface method:

```
@Override
    public void onCenterEvent() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onCenterEvent: mockLiveVideoNumber = " + mockLiveVideoNumber);
        if(mockLiveSectionNumber == 667 && mockLiveVideoNumber == 5){
            Log.i(TAG, "onCenterEvent: picture taken");
            handler.removeCallbacks(noInputTimer);
            handler.removeCallbacks(wrongInputTimer);
            pictureTaken();
            handler.postDelayed(correctInputTimer, threeSeconds);
        }else{
            handler.postDelayed(wrongInputTimer, threeSeconds);
        }

    }
```

and here is the pictureTaken() method:

```
private void pictureTaken(){
        setPhotoTakenVisibility(true);
        Log.i(TAG, "pictureTaken: " + photoTakenVisibility);
        setPhotoFlashVisibility(true);
        Log.i(TAG, "flashVisibility: " + photoFlashVisibility);
        handler2.postDelayed(photoFlashRunnable, 50);
        handler2.postDelayed(photoTakenRunnable, threeSeconds);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

My fix: Ended up being a MutableLiveData issue, where I was using .setvalue() instead of .postValue() for the photoTakenVisibility. It was a threading issue, where postValue() can be called from a background thread and still update the UI whereas .setValue() doesn't.